# how to register a subscriber the right way in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have this ionic 2 provider:

```
@Injectable()
export class SettingsProvider {

    settingsData: SettingsDataModel = new SettingsDataModel(2, 2);
    subscriber = null;

    constructor(public http: Http, public storage: Storage) {
        console.log('Hello SettingsProvider Provider');
    }

    load(): void {
        this.storage.ready().then(() => {

            // Or to get a key/value pair
            this.storage.get('settingsData').then((val) => {
                this.subscriber(); // how to notify the subscriber (a differerent typescript class) there was a change the right way in ionic 2?
            });

        })
    }

    save() {
        this.storage.set('settingsData', this.settingsData);
        this.subscriber(); // how to notify the subscriber (a differerent typescript class) there was a change the right way in ionic 2?
    }

    subscribe(callback) { // how to register a subscriber the right way in ionic 2?
        this.subscriber = callback;
    }


}
```

I have implemented the ability that another class wanting to subscribe and get notifications by custom code (fragile one) what would be the implementation that another class could subscribe to it the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to notify another chunk of code, such as another service, you can expose an observable property that represents an ongoing series of events. We can do this using a `Subject`.

Here is what this would look like

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/subject';

// singleton can use true privacy.
const settingsEventSource = new Subject<SettingsDataModel>();

@Injectable() export default class SettingsProvider {

  constructor(readonly http: Http, readonly storage: Storage) { }

  get settings$() {
    return settingsEventSource.asObservable(); // prevent others from sourcing events
  }

  settingsData = new SettingsDataModel(2, 2);

  async load() {
    await this.storage.ready();
    try {
      this.settingsData = await this.storage.get('settingsData');
      settingsEventSource.next(this.settingsData);
    }
    catch (e) {
      settingsEventSource.error('Error loading settings.');
    }
  }

  async save() {
    try {
      await this.storage.set('settingsData', this.settingsData);
      settingsEventSource.next(this.settingsData);
    }
    catch (e) {
      settingsEventSource.error('Error saving settings.');
    }
  }
}
```

A subscriber would look like this

```
import SettingsProvider from './settings-provider';
import SetttingsDataModel from './settings-data-model';

@Injectable() export default class SomeService {
  constructor(settingsProvider: SettingsProvider) {
    settingsProvider.subscribe(settings => { 
      this.settings = setttings;
    });
  }
}
```